# How can i put the icon on the left top in my textFormField/ textfield?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio, text

I have an textfield but the problem is that the icon is still centered in the middel while the textfield is expanded. How can i make the icon go on the left site of the hint text (left top)?

```
TextFormField reusableTextField2(String text, IconData icon,TextEditingController controller) {
  return TextFormField(

    controller: controller,
    cursorColor: Colors.white,
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9)),

    decoration: InputDecoration(
      
      prefixIcon: Icon(

        icon,
        color: Colors.white70,

      ),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 0, style: BorderStyle.none)),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 20),


      labelText: text,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9)),
      filled: true,
      floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
      fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
      alignLabelWithHint: true,
    ),
    maxLines: null,
    minLines: 7,
  );
}
```

[image: This is the TextField]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it with `Stack` widget, then set the icon separately, but so it gets aligned vertically the same as the `TextFormField` widget, give it a vertical `padding` same as the `TextFormField`'s `contentPadding`. like this:

```
Widget reusableTextField2(
    String text, IconData icon, TextEditingController controller) {
  final verticalPadding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20);
  return Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
        cursorColor: Colors.white,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9)),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
              borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 0, style: BorderStyle.none)),
          contentPadding:
              verticalPadding + EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          labelText: text,
          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9)),
          filled: true,
          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
          fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
          alignLabelWithHint: true,
        ),
        maxLines: null,
        minLines: 7,
      ),
      Container(
        padding: verticalPadding,
        child: Icon(icon),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but i have oned more question. How can i make the text align the icon in the middel? The text is now a bit higher than the icon.

Comment: I didn't get what you want, can you clarify

Comment: in the second picture you see that the text field is an other color how can i change this back? and i want the text to be aligned with the icon like the third picture